# Setting no-focus ring aka no space bar sends mouse down in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, focus, nsbutton

I have a small application written in Objective-C that demonstrates a "default Key Equivalent" that I have not been able to remove. The application has two buttons:

- Button1 that on press sets the text label to "Button 1 pressed"
- Button2 that on press sets the text label to "Button 2 pressed"

[image: Screenshot of the sample application]

That all works, however, when I press the space bar, button 1 is pressed: highlight, depress, signal sent to the handler.  Now, in this example, there is a focus ring, and the tab key changes the focus from button to button, and then the space bar is equivalent to a mouse click.  (In my original application there are no focus rings so this was harder to see).

Now I know that this makes sense in the general case of the buttons with focus rings, and application windows with tab to select next control.  But what can be done if we want to have only move the mouse to focus? And thus ignore space bar presses?  Should I create an NSResponder to consume these key presses?

Comment: 1&2) File an "Enhancement Request" (bug report). 3) NO! If the option to disable this "feature" existed it should be at the users discretion not the applications. As primarily a  keyboard user I'd be very annoyed with your app if you forced me to reach for the mouse. That very much breaks my normal workflow.